# setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid') not Working

Tags: jqgrid

I'm not sure whats wrong but this is not working with me, below is my code but hitting reload dont create any request to server.

```
    $("#timecard-summary-grid").jqGrid({
    url:'grid/grid_timecard_summary.php',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Date','Day','Time In','Time Out','Normal','Late','Undertime'],
    colModel :[
      {name:'date', index:'date', width:90, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'day', index:'day', width:70, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'t_in', index:'t_in', width:80, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'t_out', index:'t_out', width:80, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'tdiff', index:'tdiff', width:80, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'late', index:'late', width:80, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'undertime', index:'undertime', width:80, editable:false, align:"center", editrules:{required:true}}
    ],

    height: 'auto',
    pager: '#timecard-summary-pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20],
    sortname: 'date',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    loadonce: true, // to enable sorting locally
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    editurl: 'grid_summary_editurl.php',
    caption: '<span style="margin-left:10px;">Timecard Summary</span>',

    });
    $("#timecard-summary-grid").jqGrid('navGrid',"#timecard-summary-pager",
    {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true},
    {zIndex:5234}, //option for edit
    {zIndex:5234}, // for add
    {zIndex:5234}, // del
    {zIndex:5234,   multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true} // search
    ); 
    $("#timecard-summary-id").jqGrid("setGridParam",{datatype:"xml"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Where should I put the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the code which you posted (`jqGrid("setGridParam",datatype:"xml"})`) contains syntax error: there are no opened '{'. I hope that the problem exists only in the text of your question and not in your original code.

The next problem: you tried to change the `datatype` and reload the grid **directly after the grid will be created**. The problem is that you use `datatype: 'xml'` in the jqGrid. So immediately after the grid will be created the request to the server will be send per ajax. Request to reload the grid during pending Ajax request will be just ignored and no reloading will take place.

After the Ajax request to the server will be finished the `datatype` will be changed from `'xml'` to `'local'` corresponds to the option `loadonce: true`. So **only after the first response will be full processed** one can execute the code

```js
$("#timecard-summary-id").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "xml"})
    .trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes error is in the text of question only. Are you suggesting that I need to create a custom button that will trigger the reload when click?

Comment: Hi Oleg, got it from your anser way back year 2010, I need to put it on beforeRefresh